# Program isnt working

Tags: c, file

Im still considered a beginner in c and i started learning about files. i already built a blank file. Every time i compile this program, the file is still blank. Need help!!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

     int main()
    {
       FILE * x;
       char name[25];

       printf("enter your name: ");
       scanf("%s", &name);

       x = fopen("x1.txt", "w");

       if(x = NULL)
      {
         printf("Unable to open the file");
      }

       else
      {
         fprintf(x, "%s\n", name);

         printf("date has been entered successfully to the file");
         fclose(x);
      }


 return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Change `x = NULL` to `x == NULL`.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't do what your problem says `every time I compile the program the file is still blank`, I say that because compiling won't have any effect on the file.  However, running the program `after fixing the errors` will have an affect.

Comment: Compiling a program does not execute it. You should run it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Say exactly what you are doing in what environment and exactly what was output (errors messages, files, etc).

Comment: this line: `scanf("%s", &name);` allows the user to enter enough characters to overrun the input buffer.  This is undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: `scanf("%24s", &name);`

Comment: this line: `printf("Unable to open the file");` should be: `perror( "fopen for x1.txt for write failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding this text: "date has been entered"  perhaps you meant: "data has been entered"

Comment: this line: `printf("date has been entered successfully to the file");` leaves the text in the output buffer until the program closes.  since there are no formatting specifiers, suggest: `puts( "date has been entered successfully to the file" );`  as `puts()` appends a '\n' to the output, which will force the flush of the stdout buffer

Comment: this line: `if(x = NULL)` is an assignment, not a comparison.  You can get a lot of gray hairs trying to find that keypunch error in a large program.  However, if you make it a habit to always place the literal on the left, then the compiler would find that for you.  I.E. `if( NULL = x)` will produce a compiler error due to the assignment to a literal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file existed, and  contained my name, after making the following changes and rebuilding/running the program:

(see comments in line for reasons)
Change:

```
if(x = NULL)//assignment - as is, this statement will always evaluate 
            //to false, as x is assigned to NULL.
```

To:

```
if(x == NULL)// comparison - this will test whether x is equal to NULL without changing x.
```

Change:  (this was key to your file not being populated)

```
   scanf("%s", &name);//the 'address of' operator: '&' is not needed here.
                      //The symbol 'name' is an array of char, and is
                      //located at the address of the first element of the array.
```

To:

```
   scanf("%s", name);//with '&' removed.
```

Or better:

```
   scanf("%24s", name);//'24' will prevent buffer overflows
                       //and guarantee room for NULL termination.
```

Yet one more method to address the comment about *[not using scanf at all...](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)*:

```
char buffer[25];//create an additional buffer
...
memset(name, 0, 25);//useful in loops (when used) to ensure clean buffers
memset(buffer, 0, 25);
fgets(buffer, 24, stdin);//replace scanf with fgets...
sscanf(buffer, "%24s", name);//..., then analyze input using sscanf 
                             //and its expansive list of format specifiers 
                             //to handle a wide variety of user input.
                             //In this example, '24' is used to guard 
                             //against buffer overflow.
```

Regarding the last method, here is a page *[detailing the versatility](http://docs.roxen.com/(en)/pike/7.0/tutorial/strings/sscanf.xml)* of handling user input strings using sscanf.

Comment: or change it to `scanf("%s", &name[0]);` :)

Comment: @KevinDTimm - true.  But convention allows for either.  Thanks.

Comment: `scanf("%24s", name);` is even better because it's safer against buffer overflows.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - nice suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: @ryyker - you missed my wink   :(

Comment: @KevinDTimm - I did..., and admit was a little confused by the suggestion :)  Thanks

Comment: @philipxy - In the range of [good:evil] I do not find scanf to be too far toward the evil side when used for simple user input. But I did find your comment very instructive, and it made a good point. Thanks for your input.